# Calculate worker connections based on CPU/RAM Utilization

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am new to nginx. My machine is centos 6 with 4 CPU and 8 GB of ram. As per recommendation my

worker_process = 4. I have set worker_connections to 500 for 2000 max clients but load average goes upto 3-4 and sometimes upto 7 with near about 150 connections only.And which sometimes cause 504 gateway timeout issue.

Average CPU utilization for each php-fpm process is 10 to 15 % which sometimes goes upto 30 % and memory utilization is 0.1 % to 0.5%

What optimal value should i set for worker_connections and how to calculate my max client value based on cpu utilization.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU usage is caused by PHP-FPM, that is, your PHP code. Changing your nginx settings will have no visible effect on your CPU usage.

Study your scripts and PHP setup. For example, if you don't have PHP Opcode cache enabled, enabling that helps a lot.